# How load docker-machine env inside Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-machine

I'm looking for a way to load docker-machine env with my python kernel. Now when I run build with docker, I'm obtain the follow error:

```
Running S2I version "v1.1.14-dirty"
FATAL: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
make[1]: *** [docker/build] Error 1
```

If I run with `%%bash`, works, but it are not usual:

```
%%bash

eval "$(docker-machine env)"

make docker/build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepending with eval works fine:

```
!eval "$(docker-machine env)" && make docker/build
```